# Dependency injection with OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, unity-container

I'm using Unity DI + OWIN + ASP.NET WebAPI and want to wire up Unity and OWIN, otherwise things like the `SecurityStampValidator` don't work.

In Startup.Auth.cs I have:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() =>
    UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>());
```

However, this seems to be wrong because the default implementation of `IDependencyResolver` as given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) creates a child container/scope for each request and above code looks like it's resolving in the parent container.

How can I get the current scope or child container?

This here returns `null`:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => 
    (ApplicationUserManager)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ApplicationUserManager)));
```